# Burninated because of [multiple] reasons

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

*This tag has been burninated. Please do not recreate it. If you need advice on which tag to use, see the answer below. If you see this tag reappearing, it may need to be blacklisted.*

---

I recently came across the [multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiple) tag, which I'd like to see burn. The main reason is that it's not a programming concept, thus not on-topic for the site.

The tag has 194 questions, 54 followers (somehow), no wiki or excerpt, and there's virtually no commonality between questions on this tag.

---

**Burnination criteria:**

*Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?*

I'd say no, it often doesn't describe the questions at all.

*Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?*

No here also, the concept of single vs multiple is pretty much a core concept that can be applied to anything, but I wouldn't consider it on-topic

*Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?*

Nope, you often can't deduce anything about the information in the question by seeing this tag.

*Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?*

I'd say yes here, but that doesn't make it a good tag.

---

**In response to what the benefit from burninating this tag is:**

I think the main benefit is that existence of such a tag encourages wrongly using tags, making posts harder to find. Tags should reflect the categories in which the question falls, and not be a description of the question.

Take for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49893040/7296893) tagged *excel-vba rows value multiple split-apply-combine*. Due to the many tags that are more descriptive, it's maxed at 5 tags and missing the [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel) tag, thus missing followers on that tag.

Of course, there are many more examples, (non-Excel too). These were two both posted this week.

[This one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49830669/7296893) doesn't have either [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel) or [excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba), thus Excel users won't find the question. It's maxed at 5 tags, and imo only the first one helps the question get found.

---

I think since the tag adds so little to the questions, it will be relatively low effort to burn this tag. We can just do a cleanup, and then remove the tag from the remaining questions, without having to worry about finding alternative tags.

Comment: This is an exponentially bad tag

Comment: While looking at those tagged question, I noticed a question also tagged with [appearance], which might also be a candidate for burning?

Comment: I'de say burn it. It

Comment: Now since [I started a battle](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366186/do-we-need-to-rethink-clarify-criteria-for-burnination) and you are hot on meta, let me ask you what damage does this tag do?, does it create confusion?, does it generate off-topic question?, should we really burniate it (review all 200 questions) or are you only asking for it to be removed by staff since it is a useless tag?

Comment: @PetterFriberg I've added a section explaining why the tag is harmful (was away, so couldn't reply immediately). I still feel like it should be removed, though I appreciate the need to prioritize burninating harmful tags (honestly, I'd rather see my request for [tag:access] come true since it's more harmful, but that will be a way larger effort). If there was a possibility to skip cleanup and just remove the tag and handle the orphans (like the internet burnination), I would be for it, but that's not up for repeats afaik.

Comment: Thanks Erik, for me user maxing out tags to add is enough reason (they will just find another tag) and yes the [access] tag is a good example where a clean up will help future users. *I'm a bit sorry that I took my stand on your question, since I know the effort you put into SO, but yeah all these upvotes should have been on your [access] request*

Comment: Stats at the start of featuring, Q: 169/-2, Answer saying Yes +7/-20.

Comment: I'm literally leaving on a short vacation right now. I'll try to stay involved in the discussion and burnination if there's consensus, but I might be a little slower and less involved than usual.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth enjoy

Comment: I am unsure what the negative result on the Answer (+8/-21 now) is supposed to mean.

Comment: @Pac0 pretty sure that it's because of the starting one line. Anyone sees that "Time to take a stand", they downvote. (I liked the intent behind the answer though).

Comment: *Lets just hope that the people that are actually doing the burnation are the ones that downvote and not the ones that upvote*

Comment: @Pac0 The true result is that we will burniate also the [multiple] tags and then create some crazy new tags like [multiple-select], [multiple-insert], [multiple-columns], [css-multiple-column-layout], ohh well maybe we already have them?... I guess we are set!, we probably only need to add 1 tag to all questions in the future, like [sql-batch-insert-multiple-records-tanks-in-advantage] ;)

Comment: Clearly, there are [multiple] reasons to get rid of this tag.

Comment: @BhargavRao may I suggest to only "feature on Meta" burnination posts with at least 1 answer with a positive score? I.e: please post an answer with community approval before entering phase 2.

Comment: @Cœur Lemme know as to how exactly that would that help and I'll try to follow your advice from the next time.

Comment: @Cœur Oh, that's not an issue. Ping me when that happens, and I'll hammer the other post as a dupe.

Comment: @Coeur that's only true on the regular site, not on meta. In fact, one question has already been marked as a duplicate of this one, and has been deleted since

Comment: BURN IT! 
If it floats then it's a witch...

Comment: Stats at the end of featuring, Q: 222/-3, Answer causing confusion +18/--43. The community has voted in favor of burnination.

Comment: I agree, this was a well-composed post, most people will find the tag universal, but as you said, it doesn't make it a good tag since it is not specific

Answer (score 7):

[multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiple) has been *burninated*.

[image]

Thanks to everyone who participated.

---

## Progress:

The [multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiple) tag is in the process of being burninated. You can help out by reviewing the questions with this tag, and...

- **editing** questions (to improve the question *and* remove the tag),
- **flagging/closing** questions that are duplicates/off-topic/unclear/too broad/opinion-based,
- filtering on this tag in the [Close Vote Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/?filter-tags=multiple),
- **voting** on questions with this tag,
- voting to **delete** the questions with this tag (after they have been closed, and only if the entire Q&A contains nothing of value). However, keep in mind that at the end of the burnination process all closed questions containing this tag will be deleted automatically. Thus, there's rarely a need to vote to delete these questions.

Here are some quick links to get you started:

- [Open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmultiple%5D+closed%3Ano)
- [Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmultiple%5D+closed%3Ayes)
- [Unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmultiple%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano)
- [No Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmultiple%5D+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3Ano)

## Remember that burnination is a *clean-up* effort!

#### Salvage whatever possible by editing and re-tagging.

We don't want to destroy value, so salvaging a post should be your first priority. If a question can be saved, please edit it. Your edit should improve *all* problems with the question *and* remove the [multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiple) tag, possibly replacing it with another tag, as described above in "Observations/Retag Guidance".

#### Unsalvageable questions should just be flagged/closed. They don't need to be retagged.

If the question is not appropriate for this site, then don't worry about removing the [multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiple) tag—just flag/close the question it is attached to.

At the end of the burnination process, all questions that still remain with the [multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiple) tag should have been closed. These will be mass-deleted, which will remove the tag from the system automatically, with minimal disruption.

#### Ask for help if you need it.

If you have any questions about specific questions you come across, or the process in general, please feel free to leave a comment on this post. You can also drop into the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) for real-time advice and discussion.

Comment: You don't give any retagging guidance.

Comment: @Cœur  do go ahead and [edit] the answer, it's a CW, it's everyone's effort!

Comment: How to contact the 54 followers about that?

Comment: @Cœur why do you need to contact followers of a tag?  (there's no way to do that, afaik)

Comment: Why I don't see the post pinned in the right box anymore? Only 40 questions taken care of so far. I thought it should be featured for a minimum of 36–48 hours. Or is that... does it mean that the whole community, with a featured post, only took care of 1 single tag edit per hour?

Comment: The post is featured only during Phase 2 of the burnination process. It was featured for 98 hours.

Comment: @BhargavRao No open questions left in the tag

Comment: @Machavity on it