# The [circular] tag has been burninated

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

*This tag has been burninated. Please do not recreate it. If you need advice on which tag to use, see the answer below. If you see this tag reappearing, it may need to be blacklisted.*

---

There is a [circular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/circular) tag, which is rather vaguely described as follows:

> A logical fallacy in which the developer begins with what he is trying to end up with, like class A extends B, class B extends A.

Questions are on everything to drawing circles on GUIs to implementing circular queues to circular references and dependencies.

Given how ambiguous this is, can this tag be sent to the [circular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/circular) file?

To explicitly address the burnination criteria:

**Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**
Not even close - even its tag Wiki is really vague as to what the tag is for.

**Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**
This could refer to a number of topics, but the tag admittedly doesn't appear to be drawing a lot of off-topic questions. So, the answer to this is "maybe, depends on what topic you're referring to." Many of the topics (e.g. questions about circular references or dependencies) *are* on topic, but this could just as easily refer to off-topic questions. Even the tag Wiki's description is only dubiously on-topic.

**Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**
Not really - given how ambiguous this is, if I were to filter on the tag, I'd have no idea what kind of questions I was going to get.

**Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**
No, I listed a few examples of multiple contradictory meanings that this tag could have above.

Comment: Wow, that’s a terrible description.

Comment: This tag seems like a job for Trogdor.

Comment: @Ry- Yeah, it's pretty bad. There's absolutely zero consistency in what kind of question are tagged with this either.

Comment: Perhaps that definition could be more compatible with a [circularity] tag rather than [circular]?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not what a logical fallacy is.

Comment: Note: the process for burnination is described [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination); notably, there are 4 questions you should answer.

Comment: Looks like a reasonable chunk could be retagged as [circular-dependency]

Comment: That there is no consistency is questions using this tag is mostly to blame for lacking a tag description. Lets first provide that, and then clean up the tag. At least for circular dependencies I can see a use-case here on SO, for something like drawing circles in UI's I don't see the need for a specific [circular] tag.

Comment: @Luuklag No one reads tag descriptions.

Comment: Can you perhaps add a reason why this tag is harmful, as per [this request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366186/7296893)? There's not yet concensus that this is required, but it would help your case. I see it's ambiguous, but I don't immediately see real harm.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth ambiguity is the harm, surely? If a term is ambiguous and used to describe multiple unrelated scenarios, then it cannot be used for any sort of navigation or analytical purposes, other than in order to disambiguate it, so it wastes the time of users who would utilise unambiguous equivalents, such as the [circular-dependency] tag mentioned previously, as well as time wasted in managing inappropriate usage.

Comment: Just to get a clear summary, here are the others tags related to [circular] : http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/851692/circular-related-tags

Comment: [What is the key to tagging success? Burninate the correct tags!  How do you know you burninated the correct tags?  You know because you have tagging success.  So the key to tagging success is (circular) reasoning?  Yes, because (circular) reasoning is the key.](http://dilbert.com/strip/2013-05-25)

Comment: Stats at the time of featuring: Q: +64/-4, No answers

Comment: Is "circular file" British slang?

Comment: @KyleDelaney American too (at least I've heard it in the U.S. before).

Comment: @KyleDelaney No, it's [mostly American](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=circular+file+%3A+eng_us_2012%2Ccircular+file+%3A+eng_gb_2012&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccircular%20file%20%3A%20eng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccircular%20file%20%3A%20eng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @KyleDelaney I hear it a lot in the recruiting industry referring to bad resumes

Comment: I guess I've been misled by Wikipedia again: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_13

Comment: > In the United Kingdom, for instance, the expression "round file" or "circular file" is more common (in reference to trash cans typically being round).

Comment: Stats at the end of featuring Q:+112/-5, A1 (saying Yes/retag): +48/0, A2 (saying Yes): +2/-1. The community is in favor of removing the tag. (Even though the top voted answer mentions a retag, it informs at the end that all of the posts need to be retagged, which implies that we need to burn the tag).

Answer (score 50, accepted):

That's approximately 400 questions. A random sample says this is mostly a retag effort. Retags go fast because people can't run out of edits.

[circular-dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/circular-dependency) for build dependency problems

[circular-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/circular-list) is a particular data structure--a circular linked list

[circular-reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/circular-reference) for more exotic structures

[circular-buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/circular-buffer) for ring buffer questions (ring-buffer becomes circular-buffer) including circular queue and circular array

[drawing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drawing) and [geometry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/geometry) for drawing circles

There's also quite a few questions referencing a circular scroll control which I have to admit I've never heard of.  E.G. [Circular Scroll View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920694/circular-scroll-view)

Out with this ridiculously ambiguous tag; retag the lot

Comment: circular scroll view is called a carousel view  nowadays link for anyone interested->https://camo.githubusercontent.com/2117c312f0347b726c367921944d37bcc963f127/68747470733a2f2f692e696d6775722e636f6d2f535072427379382e676966

Comment: Mortarboard! Not that it matters on meta.

Comment: "people can't run out of edits" don't give them any ideas...

Comment: What about the famous circular-freehand-line aka freehand-circle? ;)

Comment: I like how both the question and the answer are by a Joshua

Answer (score 5):

[circular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/circular) has been *burninated*.

[image: trogdor]

Thanks to everyone who participated.

## Observations/Retag Guidance:

Use the following tags instead of [circular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/circular), in case the question is on-topic:

- [circular-dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/circular-dependency) for build dependency problems
- [circular-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/circular-list) is a particular data structure--a circular linked list
- [circular-reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/circular-reference) for more exotic structures
- [circular-buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/circular-buffer) for ring buffer questions (ring-buffer becomes circular-buffer) including circular queue and circular array
- [drawing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drawing) and [geometry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/geometry) for drawing circles

## Progress:

The [circular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/circular) tag is in the process of being burninated. You can help out by reviewing the questions with this tag, and...

- **editing** questions (to improve the question *and* remove the tag) (retags only edits are best left to users with full edit privileges),
- **flagging/closing** questions that are duplicates/off-topic/unclear/too broad/opinion-based,
- filtering on this tag in the [Close Vote Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/?filter-tags=circular),
- **voting** on questions with this tag,
- voting to **delete** the questions with this tag (after they have been closed, and only if the entire Q&A contains nothing of value). However, keep in mind that at the end of the burnination process all closed questions containing this tag will be deleted automatically. Thus, there's rarely a need to vote to delete these questions.

Here are some quick links to get you started:

- [Open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcircular%5D+closed%3Ano)
- [Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcircular%5D+closed%3Ayes)
- [Unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcircular%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano)
- [No Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bccircular%5D+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3Ano)

## [Track the progress of burnination](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185530/observation-room-for-circular-burnination)

[image]

## Remember that burnination is a *clean-up* effort!

#### Salvage whatever possible by editing and re-tagging.

We don't want to destroy value, so salvaging a post should be your first priority. If a question can be saved, please edit it. Your edit should improve *all* problems with the question *and* remove the [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tag) tag, possibly replacing it with another tag, as described above in "Observations/Retag Guidance". (Edits, specially re-tags, are best left to users with [full edit privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit))

#### Unsalvageable questions should just be flagged/closed. They don't need to be retagged.

If the question is not appropriate for this site, then don't worry about removing the [circular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/circular) tag—just flag/close the question it is attached to.

At the end of the burnination process, all questions that still remain with the [circular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/circular) tag should have been closed. These will be mass-deleted, which will remove the tag from the system automatically, with minimal disruption.

#### Ask for help if you need it.

If you have any questions about specific questions you come across, or the process in general, please feel free to leave a comment on this post. You can also drop into the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) for real-time advice and discussion.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot think of a single programming question that would be improved by adding this tag.  Logical fallacies aren't exactly on-topic in a coding question, although they may be in *answers*.

As already noted, the vast variety of (mis-)uses it has been put to have also made it essentially worthless.  It appears that it has been applied anywhere that involves round shapes: round UI elements, circle drawing, radial graphs, drawing text in circles.  Occasionally it gets used in place of the the more specific [circular-dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/circular-dependency), [circular-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/circular-list), [circular-reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/circular-reference) and [circular-buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/circular-buffer).

After browsing through a few pages of questions I didn't find a single one that appeared to match the definition.  It appears that none of them would suffer if we simply removed the tag.