# Should we burninate [method-invocation]?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, burninate-request

All modern languages support something like a *function* or a *method* which can get invoked, so I don't see what value [method-invocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/method-invocation) adds to a question. It has no tag wiki, 1 follower and 115 questions tagged so far.

So I think that this tag should be burninated.

1. **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

   As already said in the beginning. [method-invocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/method-invocation) doesn't add any real value. It is the same as tagging it with [programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/programming) or something similar common.
2. **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

   Every question here is about some form of programming to which invoking a method belongs. So I guess it is.
3. **Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

   No. As said already 3 times. Invoking a method is not an information which improves the answer. Answering questions tagged [method-invocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/method-invocation) need much much more than just knowing someone is calling a function.
4. **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

   I suppose so.

---

**EDIT**

I agree with the current answer that some questions actively ask about tracing. And in that context it actually makes sense, but only combined with [tracing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tracing).

Many others just add it also as a meta-tag. So should we just remove the tag from those questions that don't actively ask about tracing?

Comment: As per [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366186/7296893), can you describe why this tag is harmful? A tag just being useless is not a strong reason for removal. If it actually caused harm (leads to mistagging/confusion/off-topic questions), your case for removal would be a lot stronger.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth thanks for that link. Regarding it in that perspective, this tag is not harmful in the way that it is missleading.

Comment: This is definitely not a meta tag. See also: [The Death of Meta Tags](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/)

Answer (score 10):

I partially disagree: many questions tagged [method-invocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/method-invocation) are precisely about method invocation (tracing them, or using specific utilities to achieve them especially in the context of reflection).

I still agree regarding the usefulness of the tag: Nobody can be interested in method invocation whatever the language or context. It's at the same time too precise and too wide.

And the problems related to method invocation won't be the same if you're trying to log them in javascript or if you're trying to achieve them on dynamically loaded classes in Java.

SO would be better without this tag.

*(it doesn't matter much though)*

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I agree that it is useful in the context of tracing. Should we consider just removing the tag where the question's not about tracing or the invocation of the method, but where it's used as a meta-tag?